# Build a python source package from a wheel

Tags: python, python-3.x, packaging, python-wheel, python-packaging

I want to distribute a tool written in Python 3 as a debian package via a company-internal repository.

This is easily possible using [stdeb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stdeb/0.8.5), however the tool depends on other python packages as well.

As said in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/508608/293242), the most correct way to do this would be to re-package all dependencies as debian packages and add them to the same repository.

To do that, I've now downloaded all dependencies of my module recursively as wheels like so: `pip wheel --wheel-dir=/tmp/wheelhouse .`, so I know this is everything I will need to re-package.

I also know that I can build a valid debian-package from a python source-package using `py2dsc` which is packaged with stdeb.

However, I'm now missing one intermediate step: *How do I transform a python wheel into a python source package?*

It shouldn't be too hard, I can unzip the wheel and look at it's content, and all source and meta-files are in there. The only thing that seems to be missing is the `setup.py` that would then allow me to build a source package. Is there maybe an existing script that generates that file from the metadata? I tried to find one but came out empty handed.

Answer (score 0):

After doing more research, it looks like there are no existing tools for this.

However, there is [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm), which pretty much does the whole thing (downloading, unpacking, re-packaging) in one command.

```
fpm -s python -t deb --python-bin=python3 easydict
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't support re-packaging from binary packages (aka wheels), only source packages, which are not always provided.